# How to work with postgres exclusion constraints in alembic

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

Is there a way to create a table with a postgresql exclusion constraint in Alembic without writing literal SQL?

Consider, for example, this table:

```
CREATE TABLE reservation (
during tsrange,
EXCLUDE USING gist (during WITH &&)
);
```

Exclusion constraints do not seem to be among among the available constraint types in alembic.

As SQLAlchemy supports `ExcludeConstraints`

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ExcludeConstraint, TSRANGE

class RoomBooking(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'room_booking'

    room = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    during = Column(TSRANGE())

    __table_args__ = (
        ExcludeConstraint(('room', '='), ('during', '&&')),
    )
```

but alembic does not seem to recognize them, I'm wondering if there are other ways to reflect such exclusion constraints in my schema revision history.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ran into the same problem. The solution in the alembic:

You need to import the exclusion constraint on the top of the script:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ExcludeConstraint

op.create_table('mission_event_schedule',
                   sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
                   sa.Column('ts_range', postgresql.TSTZRANGE(), nullable=True),
                   sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
                   ExcludeConstraint(('ts_range','&&'))
                   )
```

Comment: How to add ExcludeConstraint to an existing table?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update an existing table with ExcludeConstraint, version 0.9 has `create_exclude_constraint`. 
Reference: [create_exclude_constraint](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.create_exclude_constraint)